# Choosing between network (Ethernet or WiFi) programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

On my mac I have two kinds of networks available - Ethernet, WiFi.

While making a server call, can I somehow control which network channel to use for making the server call? So, before making server call, I want to specify the network channel to be used for that call - Ethernet or WiFi.

How can this be achieved using objective C. I am working on a cocoa application.

Answer (score 0):

I assume both NIC's are connected to Internet (so both have a IP):

I don't think you can solve it within code (not 100% sure). But what you could do is setup some local routes, configuring  which traffic goes over what NIC.

Look at the route command ('man route').

This might help you:

https://serverfault.com/questions/100613/public-traffic-to-go-over-1-nic-and-private-traffic-to-use-another-nic

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the routes available with the System Configuration framework.  In scutil(8) you can see the routes that are presently installed in the `State:/Network/Service/*` dictionaries, and in order to manipulate these programmatically you have to us the `SCDynamicStore` framework, which is C.

However, if you were trying to just do some ad-hoc service on WLAN only, you could use the `CoreWLAN` framework, which is in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have tried CoreWLAN framework and I am able to switch between networks. It does not deal with the Ethernet. I wanted to make sure that my call goes via Ethernet or WiFi.